# Creating RTF text for clipboard and sharing DataPackage in WinRT

Tags: windows-8, clipboard, windows-runtime, rtf

I'm sure this is just a google search away, but I can't find the right search terms to find what I'm looking for.

I've created a DataPackage that has both HTML annd plain text content. I've used this in my copy and my sharing code and it works fine. I now want to create RTF output as some apps don't seem to accept HTML clipboard content.

I'm looking for a good guide to making RTF text that can be added to the DataPackage. I just need simple formatting including changing the font family, font size, font weight and adding newlines. The data comes from a list of objects taht I want to serialise as RTF, not from a text control on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPad outputs fairly clean RTF and some other text editors do as well.  If that's not enough, you can download the [RTF Specification 1.9.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10725) although like any specification that's probably overkill for what you're doing.

You can also use the [SaveToStream method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.text.itextdocument.savetostream.aspx) on the [Document property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richeditbox.document.aspx) of a [RichEditBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richeditbox.aspx) from a Metro style app to share out as well.

Comment: Viewing the output from a a wordpad saved file seems the way to go. I was hoping for some sort of helper class, but the wordpad rtf seems to make sense.

Comment: Yup, there are a few out there http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11306/NRTFTree-A-class-library-for-RTF-processing-in-C for example, but I didn't want to put them in the answer because I've not tried/tested them in Metro style apps